# Multiple GetBetween calls

Tags: php

I'm making a script that gets multiple CSS files from a webpage and put them together using `foreach()` and `include()`.

I already found the right function:

```
function GetBetween($content, $start, $end) {
    $r = explode($start, $content);

    if(isset($r[1])) {
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }

    return '';
}
```

Is there an alternative to this function to get all in an array?
How can I use this to get multiple strings in an array? 
For example:

```
foreach($css = GetBetween($page, '<link rel="stylesheet" href="','"') { 
    include("$css"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually by returning an array from the function you could iterate over it. Example:

```
$cssFiles = GetBetween($page, '<link rel="stylesheet" href="','"');
foreach ($cssFiles as $cssFile)
{ 
    include($cssFile); 
}
```

However your `GetBetween` function does not return an array so far. Also you're trying to parse HTML here, you don't need to write a function to parse it, but instead you can make use of the existing HTML Parser in PHP:

```
/**
 * All stylesheet files within a HTML source
 */
class StyleSheets extends DOMDocument implements IteratorAggregate
{
    public function __construct($source)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->loadHTML($source);
    }
    public function getIterator()
    {
        static $array;
        if (NULL === $array)
        {
            $xp = new DOMXPath($this);
            $expression = '//head/link[@rel="stylesheet"]/@href';
            $array = array();
            foreach($xp->query($expression) as $node)
                $array[] = $node->nodeValue;
        }
        return new ArrayIterator($array);
    }
}
```

You can then easily use it:

```
foreach(new StyleSheets($page) as $index => $file)
{
    printf("#%d: %s\n", $index, $file);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/TafSnmlB) / Example output:

```
#0: file1.css
#1: file2.css
#2: file3.css
```

Technically you could do something similar with a string search as you do with your GetBetween function making it return an array as well. However as it's HTML I suggest you use a HTML parser instead so it's more fail-safe.